# Android Studio - Assistance with Button Repeating

Tags: java, android

I am a bit stumped on what I need to do next. I am attempting to create an app that when a button is pressed, it generates a quote. Initially when I hit the button, a word appears but when I try to hit the button again, it doesn't print out another word.

```
package com.example.under.funfacts;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

import static com.example.under.funfacts.R.id.PressMe;
import static com.example.under.funfacts.R.id.quote;
import static com.example.under.funfacts.R.id.text2;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView txt;
Button btn;

String[] quotes = new String[] {"texas", "jersey", "Pennsylvania", "Tennessee", "Mississippi"};
String randomQuote = quotes[(int) (Math.random()*quotes.length)];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quote);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PressMe);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txt.setText(randomQuote);


        }
    });
}
}
```

I am aware that I could possibly make a list for the quotes but I unfortunately do not know how to implement that.
Hopefully I am missing a small detail because I would like to press the button multiple times so I can see multiple words or quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your `randomQuote` variable is only set once. You should move its declaration to inside your `onClick()` method. That way it will get set every time you click the button:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String randomQuote = quotes[(int) (Math.random()*quotes.length)];
        txt.setText(randomQuote);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on josmith42's answer, if you want to keep adding words to the text, you can retrieve the existing text instead of worrying about a `List`. Something like this:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CharSequence currentText = txt.getText();
        String randomQuote = quotes[(int) (Math.random()*quotes.length)];

        if (currentText.length() == 0) {
            txt.setText(randomQuote);
        } else {
            txt.setText(currentText + " " + randomQuote);
        }
    }
});
```